# how to fix aused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

The following error occurs when I try to execute the code and app also terminates.
(Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button)

```
package com.tisu.role

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roll_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_01"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/roll"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button)

in your layout the `roll_button` is a **`TextView`** and in your acivity your trying  doing `findViewById` as `Button` that's why you are getting `ClassCastException`

> First solution is

Use this

```
val rollButton: TextView = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
```

instead of this

```
val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
```

> Second solution is

assign **`roll_button`** id to your `button` in your layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_01"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/roll_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/roll"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

### Bonus

Also read this

no need to **`findViewById`** in kotlin

- [Kotlin Android Extensions: Say goodbye to findViewById](https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/)
- [Goodbye findViewById, say hello to Synthetic Binding](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/goodbye-findviewbyid-say-hello-to-synthetic-binding-in-kotlin-d3727bd8438e)

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to set TextView id to a button . change your layout code to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_01"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/roll_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/roll"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have issue on line

```
val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
```

You are tried to convert text view as Button so you have to use like below

```
val rollButton: TextView = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set id to Button in place of TextView

```
<Button android:id="@+id/roll_button"
```